# MYSQL is not OR is NULL

Tags: mysql, null

I want to get data from the database which is either not set or has not the value of 2.

```
$sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, 
      "SELECT leto_raz, vrsta_raz, id_raz, oddal_raz, nazivodd_raz, zavod_raz 
       FROM ".$razpis." WHERE Oddano_raz = 2 AND dont_raz != 2 LIMIT $limit ");
```

I want the dont_raz != 2 AND NOT NULL, just don't know how to make it. Searching online for a while, but does not find anything.

Comment: `WHERE Oddano_raz = 2 AND (dont_raz != 2 AND dont_raz is not null)`

Comment: and use parameters or for ever be condemned by sql injection

Comment: You can't use parameter for a table name (`$razpis`) only for the limit (`$limit`) @JuanCarlosOropeza

Comment: Is smaller than 2, or, is not equal to 2? You suggest the first one in your title and the second in the main body of the question.

Comment: != OR IS NOT NULL is the what I wanted. I managed it to make it work. Thanks to @Phiter